# Receiving CrossThreadMessagingException while Debugging WinForms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging

I am using Wndows XP SP3 x86 + VSTS 2008 to write a simple Windows Forms application using C#. There is a button called `button1` and here is the event handler for its click event, when executing the if statement, there is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException`. Does anyone have any good ideas what is wrong?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string recording = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["recording"];

    // exception thrown when executing the following if statement
    if (recording.Equals("enable", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        CameraEncoder.Stop();
    }
}
```

Some more code:

```
static WMEncoder CameraEncoder = new WMEncoder();
```

EDIT1:

I am confused how to apply Marc's idea of using `Invoke` in my code. Should I use the following code segment?

```
CameraEncoder.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
{
        CameraEncoder.Stop();
});
```

Comment: I have seen your great comments, I have added mine. Please help to review and share your great ideas again. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the problem when we see this (regularly) is something like a worker thread or a timer updating the UI - but a button click should be raised through the UI thread, so I don't think it is the "usual problem".

So: what is `camera`? And what is `Recording`? Neither is explained, and we can't guess without introducing extra variables...

Depending on what they are, maybe this'll work...

```
camera.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
{
    if (camera.Equals("enable", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        Recording.Stop();
    }        
});
```

But without knowing what `canera` **is**, I'm clutching at straws...

Comment: Thanks Marc! 1. There is typo and no camera object, only recording object as string. My bad. :-) 2. CameraEncoder is a Windows Media Encoder object which I starts it in Form Load method, but I do not think it is CameraEncoder's issue since when executing if statement (not hit CameraEncoder.Stop yet), there is such exception. Any ideas to analyze further? 3. I find on Windows Vista and Windows Server 2003, my code works fine, only has issues on Windows XP.

Comment: What is "MethodInvoker"? I did not find a keyword or function named "MethodInvoker" in C#?

Comment: MethodInvoker is a delegate type in System.Windows.Forms - that simply returns void and accepts no parameters.

Comment: Re the update: I strongly suspect that the exception is actionally on the Stop(); line... a string equality test doesn't trigger thread affinity. Do you have any event handlers on events from the CameraEncoder? I wonder if that is the real issue...

Comment: A further question, 1. can we create WMEncoder object from main GUI thread? 2. "I strongly suspect that the exception is actionally on the Stop(); line" -- but exception thrown before we reach Stop line in VSTS, why you think exception will be caused by some line of code which is not executed yet? :-) 3. I only call Start/Stop method of WMEncoder, no event on the instance of this type. Any further ideas?

Comment: 4. You use camera.Invoke to fix issue that you think in UI thread (callback of button click event handler), we should not call method of other class?

Comment: 1: I would assume that you should *only* create it there; 2: debuggers are often off by a line or so, and strings don't have thread-affinity

Comment: 4: "we should not call method of other class?" - sorry, I don't understand the question

Comment: Thanks Marc, 1. so you suggest to create WMEncoder object in the main UI thread? I have this confusion because clemahieu mentioned below that seems we should not create WMEncoder object in the main UI thread. Appreciate if you could clarify. :-) 2. How do you prove it is the Stop method issue? 3. Sorry for my bad English, my question is, why you think using Invoke will solve my issue -- because Invoke will execute the instructions in another thread other than the main UI thread?

Comment: 4. Another confusion is how to use your Invoke method in my code since there are some typo in my original code. I have posted my new code in my original reply EDIT1 section, please have a review whether my code is correct? Invoke and MethodInvoker is new to me. :-)

Comment: 1: I can see clemahieu saying **do** create it on the UI thread... how are you currently creating it? 2: perhaps add some trace info "about to do this", "did this", etc. Re the "why" - Control.Invoke pushes work onto the thread that owns a component, which (for controls) should be the UI thread. It sounds very much like you are creating this control on a non-UI thread...

Comment: 1. Marc, sorry for my bad English, let me final confirm, you mean we can create WMEncoder object inside UI thread correct? 2. I think your solution of using Invoke is on the basis that you think we should access Stop method of WMEncoder from the main UI thread, correct? But WMEncoder is not a Windows Forms control, it is from Windows Media Encoder 9 SDK, so it does not have the inherited Invoke method. I am confused how to apply your solution. Appreciate if you could clarify. :-)

Comment: 3. "It sounds very much like you are creating this control on a non-UI thread" -- I declare a static object of WMEncoer named CameraEncoder as a static member of the Forms class (the form class composites button control), in this case does the CameraEncoder created by main UI thread or not?

Comment: OK, I don't have the WM SDK, so I can't try it; if there is no Invoke then.... hmmm... don't know. Have you *tried* keeping the encoder local to the form and creating it on the UI thread?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the camera object is created and managed by another thread.. Could you expose more code regarding the camera object?

Comment: Sorry my typo, there is no camera object,  just recordering object as string, any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I know `WMEncoder` is a `COM` object.  You might try creating `CameraEncoder` in the GUI thread instead of a different thread.

Comment: I declare it as static object, so which thread creates the static object, main GUI thread? How to prove it?

Comment: I declare it as static object -- I mean I declare it as static object in the forms class.

Comment: "You might try creating CameraEncoder in the GUI thread instead of a different thread." -- yes, but what is wrong?

Comment: I haven't done COM in a long time but there is the concept of Single Threaded Apartment and Multi Threaded Apartment.  In STA a COM object receives function calls through a background window message queue.  This is the same type of message queue that GUI elements use; you get a similar exception with cross-thread GUI calls.

Comment: "you get a similar exception with cross-thread GUI calls" -- I agree. But I am creating a WMEncoder object in the main UI thread, not making cross-thread GUI calls. Are they the same thing as you mentioned?