# Textbox exception with timer

Tags: c#, exception, textbox, timer

I have a problem with this code.

It's generates this exception:

> Text' threw an exception of type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
        TimerTick, null, TimeSpan.Zero, new TimeSpan(0, refresh , 0));
}

void TimerTick(object state)
{
    LoggerTxt.AppendText("fsjdaò");

 }
```

LoggerTxt is a `TextBox`.

How I can do?

thanks

Comment: It is probably caused by a Watch expression on the Text property of the control.  I've been seeing this *debugger* exception pop up over the past few weeks, something is wrong.  Do you have the beta service pack for VS2010 installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access GUI components in a Windows Forms application only from within the foreground thread. (I think, this is also true for WPF applications)

Since you are trying to call a function on the `TextBox` (a GUI component) from the timer function (in the background thread) you get the exception.

Try

```
LoggerTxt.Invoke( 
    new MethodInvoker( 
        delegate { LoggerTxt.AppendText("fsjdaò"); } ) );
```

To avoid the exception.

Also see the documentation of [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) for more on this topic and [this similar SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012178/receiving-crossthreadmessagingexception-while-debugging-winforms-application).

Comment: There is `dispatcher` object in WPF which could be used in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

As Uwe has commented you cannot access or modify a GUI component not on the GUI thread therefore you have to usually invoke this.

If you are going to do this a lot why not add this class to your projects so that all control objects have this method exposed to them.

You can use `LoggerTxt.RunInGUIThread(x => x.AppendText("fsjdao"));`

```
public static class ControlExtensions

{

  public static void RunInGUIThread<TControl>(this TControl control, Action<TControl> action)

    where TControl: Control

  {

    if (control.InvokeRequired)

      control.Invoke(action, control);

    else

      action(control);

  }

}
```